# Freeze Android orientation to portrait (Phonegap App)?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developing a Android app using Phonegap - Is there any way in which I can freeze the screen rotation to only display portrait - so it doesnt move when the phone is tilted landscape?

I tried adding-

```
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

to my android manifest file but this hasn't worked.  I'm developing using Android 2.1

Cheers
Paul

Comment: Did you add the screenOrientation to the Activity Tag?

Comment: show your manifest file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just add the following code to your manifest file:

```
<activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Are you adding following code to activity only?

Comment: Cheers for your help - works a treat - I didn't initially realise I needed to add it to each activity.  Cheers.Paul